# How to express wait for (at most) how long and wait for something at the same time

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

I am not a native English speaker and am writing a command line program interacting with the end user. I need to prompt the end user in my program before a long wait (a kind of polling until some condition fulfilled or timeout). I want to express following:

1. The purpose of such waiting/polling, i.e. you are waiting for some condition is/becomes true (e.g. the remote host/server is/becomes reachable/available);
2. The maximum waiting time (i.e. the timeout). Hence the waiting/polling will last for at most e.g. 10 minutes.

I am currently using `Waiting at most 10 minutes for remote host reachable ...` as my prompt. But it looks a little bit weird as I did not see similar expression, e.g. in my programming manual. It looks like something I (badly) "invented" which may be absolutely wrong. I tried looking up dictionaries and googling. But there are only examples like "wait (for) 10 minutes", and "wait for something" or "wait to do something".

One more question, how could I say if I want to emphasize the status change, i.e. the remote host **becomes** reachable (from unreachable)? Is `Waiting at most 10 minutes until the remote host becomes reachable ...` OK? How about `Waiting for remote host becoming reachable in 10 minutes ...`?

Thanks a lot.

**-- Update --**

My program is a testing suite, consisting of many testing steps. It will prompt the current step especially such step is time consuming. So usually my prompt looks like `Checking something A ...`, `Testing something B ...`, and `Waiting for something C ...`. It would be better if it can have similar structure, or can express the meaning of "the thing I am doing ...". Anyway, this is just preferred. If my prompt is wrong in language usage or misleading, it still need be re-phrased for correctness.

Comment: _Waiting for the remote host to become available (10 min. at most)_ would be my favoured version.

Comment: If you're a native speaker, this isn't a question about learning English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two things to say, so it's fine to use two sentences.  In other software I've seen things like

> Waiting for remote host. This may take several minutes...

Feel free to use "ten minutes", but do your users really need to know the exact length of the timeout?  (and saying "several" avoids future bugs when someone changes the timeout to 7 minutes without changing the message)

Comment: Yes. I understood two sentences could help. But here I want to tell the end user the current status (what is doing now) of my program. You can imagine a list of "Doing ..." popping out, like "Checking ...", "Testing ...", blah blah. It would be better if it look similar or keep the last three dots. This program is a kind a testing suite. Some of its testing steps have pre-defined timeout/deadline. Prompting them out is just trying to give the end user a clear view of current step. Anyhow, good point for bug avoiding and thanks for helping. :-)

Comment: I think my answer does tell the end user the current status.  It is "Waiting..."  or specifically it is "Waiting for the remote host"  If you want three dots, just use them.